# Prove that $E=\{x\geq0\ |\ f(x+\frac{1}{f(x)})\geq 2f(x)\}$ Lebesgue measure is at most 2.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[1,\infty)$ be continuous strictly monotonic increasing function.

Prove that $E=\{x\geq0\ |\ f(x+\frac{1}{f(x)})\geq 2f(x)\}$ Lebesgue measure is at most 2.

**My attempt**

I tried to prove the claim assuming $f$ is differentiable, by showing

$(1+\frac{f'(x)}{f^{2}})(f'(x+\frac{1}{f(x)})\leq2f'(x)$

Then I thought it is sufficient show that 
$E'= \{x\geq0\ |\ f(x+\frac{1}{x})\geq 2f(x)\}$
Lebesgue measure is at most 2, but is claim is wrong.
A counter-example is $f(x)=e^{x^{2}}$.

I'm basically looking for a direction to approach this expression $f(x+\frac{1}{f(x)})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n = 0,1,2, \ldots$ consider the sets
$$
 E_n = \{ x \in E \mid 2^n \le f(x) \le 2^{n+1}\} \, .
$$
$E_n$ is closed and bounded below, so that $a_n = \min E_n$ exists.

If $b > a_n + \frac{1}{f(a_n)}$ then
$$
 f(b) > f(a_n + \frac{1}{f(a_n)}) \ge 2 f(a_n) \ge 2^{n+1} 
$$
so that $b \notin E_n$.

It follows that each $E_n$ is contained the interval $[a_n, a_n + \frac{1}{f(a_n)}]$ of length $ \frac{1}{f(a_n)} \le \frac{1}{2^n}$, and the Lebesgue measure of $E = \bigcup_n E_n$ is at most $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 2$.